# Can one differentiate a series after taking its limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I made a post in my blog to show that $1+2+3+\cdots=-\frac{1}{12}$.

However a visitor of my blog commented that I can not differentiate an expression after taking its limit. Is that statement true? would that make the proof wrong?

Comment: You cannot in general interchange two limiting operations: for example, $\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{x} \neq \lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{y}{x} $.

Comment: Do you not see that the ridiculous conclusion you've drawn **shows** that you can't interchange these things in general??

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: I see no reason that you should insult me. if my question made you angry, then I am sorry but if I knew the answer, I would not be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: You are not taking a limit of the variable you are differentiating with respect to, so it is still a free variable in the resulting expression. If you tried to differentiate with respect to $n$ after taking the limit of partial sums, then yes that would be an issue.  However you are ignoring the radius of convergence of the series, which is why you are able to prove a false conclusion.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood His error in fact was not the interaction  between the limit and the derivative, so no it doesn't show anything of the sort.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi I'm not angry, and I did not mean to insult you (I apologise) - what I was trying to make clear was if you are trying to prove something, and you make an assumption which leads to a false statement, then your immediate reaction should be to say that an assumption you made was incorrect.

Comment: Grouping of terms in divergent series is not allowed [see section 3.1 on page 1191 of this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0510142).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$$
on an interval $I$, then it is true that
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n n x^{n-1}.
$$
So indeed you can take derivatives. **However**: You have that
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$$
on the interval $(-1, 1)$. The identity is not true for $x = -1$. So you do have that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}
$$
and this is tru on the interval $(-1,1)$. It isn't true for $x=-1$. Hence your proof of your Theorem 1 isn't correct.

Comment: Maybe it's overly pedantic but just because there was so much discussion about exchanging limits above: we have the derivative equal to the sum of derivatives on interval I (Thomas' first point) because the power series uniformly converges on its interval of convergence.  This is not the same as $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n x^n \rightarrow f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n x^{n-1}$$.

Answer (score 0):

Your post can be justified by using *formal* power series rather than actual infinite sums. It doesn't really work at all with typical analysis, because we would be forced to conclude that everything diverges anyways in that case and it's awful silly of a commenter to be arguing about derivatives when nothing in the post can be adequately addressed with limits. So, if we want to proceed, it is to our advantage to consider the series
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots$$
only algebraically, without referencing convergence or divergence - and we may consider that this series naturally extends forever, without referencing any partial sums or truncations of the series. That is, we put aside the idea that this is a function of a real number $x$, and just use algebraic rules (sums and products) to play with it.

Such series come with their own version of the derivative, where we define formal derivative of the above as
$$a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\ldots.$$
One may notice that this derivative satisfies the ordinary rules for addition, products, and composition, and we may treat it accordingly. Notice in particular that the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$. Now, none of this arise from analysis and we must be a little careful: *it is not perfectly clear what significance results obtained this way have when you use this in ways that are not valid in analysis*. However, given that most of the time, when you see a particular value assigned to a divergent series, it arises as some sort of analytic continuation of a series to a place where it doesn't converge, we are extremely interested when such methods yield a analytic result valid near $x=0$ - which yours is. If that sentence makes no sense to you: Sorry. But this is basically where the value $1+2+3+\ldots =\frac{-1}{12}$ comes from - we take a series, valid *somewhere*, consider it as a special type of function, and ask for the function's value somewhere that the series is *not* valid. Formal manipulations often are able to capture the leap made when we move from working with series *locally*, to working with functions *globally*.

The first bit of your argument, using this machinery, can be written somewhat like this - I intentionally avoid using division because it is not immediately obvious how division works with formal power series.

> We start with the identity
>   $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)(1-x)=1$$
>   which is clear from expanding the left side as as:
>   $$\begin{align*}1&+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots\\ & -x-x^2 -x^3-\ldots \end{align*}. $$
>   Applying the derivative to the identity and using the product rule yields:
>   $$(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots)(1-x) - (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots) = 0$$
>   and if we multiply through by $(1-x)$ we get the identity:
>   $$(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots)(1-x)^2 - (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)(1-x) = 0$$
>   and noting that $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)(1-x)=1$ by the first equation we get
>   $$(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots)(1-x)^2 = 1$$

At which point we could plug in $x=-1$ and obtain the value $\frac{1}4$ for the desired series by manipulating algebraically. We reach this conclusion without appealing to limits at all - and can find that, in so far as the notion of sums of divergent series is well-defined - the value of the one in question is $\frac{1}4$.